# Quartz: Database schema validation failed

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I am getting [this](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/main/src/Quartz/Impl/AdoJobStore/JobStoreSupport.cs#L550) error.

Quartz Version: 3.5

I have these tables created in my sql server database.

What could be the issue?

FYI, I have different databases for each tenant. It's working fine for other tenant.

[image]

Comment: I have the same error message... any solution?